# Add categorical column to data frame and match categories with existing categorical column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames containing categorical columns that are logically related to each other and contain the same number of categories (*category 1 in df1 <-> category 1 in df2, category 2 in df1 <-> category 2 in df2, etc*.). The data frames are of different lengths, and the rows are not ordered, so I cannot simply reorder and concatenate them.

I want to add the categorical variable of df2 to df1 so that the categories of both categorical columns match.

Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd

foo = pd.Categorical(values=[0,1,2,3],categories=[0,1,2,3],ordered=True)
bar = pd.Categorical(values=['b','c','b','a','d','a'],categories=['a','b','c','d'],ordered=True)

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'foo':foo})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'bar':bar})
```

```
  foo
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   3
```

```
  bar
0   b
1   c
2   b
3   a
4   d
5   a
```

I would like to get:

```
  foo bar
0   0   a
1   1   b
2   2   c
3   3   d
```

**EDIT**

The solution should also work when the two data frames contain additional columns, such as:

```
import pandas as pd

foo_1 = pd.Categorical(values=[0,1,2,3],categories=[0,1,2,3],ordered=True)
foo_2 = pd.Series(['x','y','z','x'])

bar_1 = pd.Categorical(values=['b','c','b','a','d','a'],categories=['a','b','c','d'],ordered=True)
bar_2 = pd.Series([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.5,0.6])

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'foo_1':foo_1,'foo_2':foo_2})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'bar_1':bar_1,'bar_2':bar_2})
```

Comment: Yes, both categorical variables are ordered and the categories correspond with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `map` with a `Series` the alignment is with the Series Index, which is why the first 4 rows in `df_1` are mapped to the first 4 values in `df_2`. You instead need to ensure alignment is on the categorical codes.

`Series.cat.categories` will list the categories in order.  You can create a simple dictionary from the second categorical column with enumerate and map the codes of the first.

```
d = dict(enumerate(df_2['bar'].cat.categories))
df_1['bar'] = df_1['foo'].cat.codes.map(d)

#  foo bar
#0   0   a
#1   1   b
#2   2   c
#3   3   d
```

Answer (score 0):

You could bring your index to variable and merge both datasets like so:

```
df_1.merge(df_2.reset_index(), left_on=['foo'], right_on=['index'], how='left')
```

results:

```
    foo index   bar
0   0   0       b
1   1   1       c
2   2   2       b
3   3   3       a
```